# VS2010 Design-Time error when using WCF to load design-time data

Tags: silverlight, design-time-data

gentlemens.
I have following definition in the Silverlight project, MainPage.xaml:

```
<UserControl
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Engine.Silverlight.Web.Views;assembly=Engine.Login.Model"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=model:DesignTimeModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">...
```

And class in the Engine.Login.Model project, which used for design-time data binding (everything works fine for pre-initialized properties, but):

```
    public class DesignTimeModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DesignTimeModel()
    {
        var d = Deployment.Current.Dispatcher;
        d.BeginInvoke(
            () =>
            {
                CacheClient c = new CacheClient();
                c.GetResourcesCompleted +=(s,e)=>
                    {
                        d.BeginInvoke(
                            () => this.Resources = e.Result);
                    };
                c.GetResourcesAsync();
            }
        );
```

Unfortunately, I got a System.ObjectDisposedException after WCF request completed (I tried to debug using different instance of VS by attaching to 1st VS instance process, but it does not help - same error, no additional info):

```
System.ObjectDisposedException
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Dispatcher'.
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
```

I assume the Dispatcher behavior different in the design mode.
Can you help me how to resolve the problem to get design-time data using WCF in VS2010 XAML designer?

Answer (score 0):

First, I belive that making a WCF call in a design time class isn't really a best practice! You should instead put some static dummy data.

For your problem, try using `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher` directly instead of pointing a variable to it.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236095/how-to-have-a-blendable-project-using-mvvm-light-and-wcf-ria-services)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236095/how-to-have-a-blendable-project-using-mvvm-light-and-wcf-ria-services)
[link](http://openlightgroup.net/Blog/tabid/58/EntryId/87/Silverlight-MVVM-Enabling-Design-Time-Data-in-Expression-Blend-When-Using-Web-Services.aspx)
I saw list of samples with WCF design-time, I don't know why you think its not good.
Btw, I did changes in code as you recommended - it doesn't help...